# Stack memory error create a core file?

Tags: c++, c

I have never seen this but i had this thing in my mind!

stack memory error here could be a memory corruption also.
lets say there is a stack overflow in a c/c++ program.

does it create a core dump file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the operating system and language runtime. I'll assume you're talking about some flavour of Unix/Linux, since you mention a core dump.

Typically, there will be some amount (perhaps a single page) of unmapped virtual memory beyond the stack. If you overflow by less than that amount, then the program will attempt to access that, giving a segmentation fault. If the program doesn't handle the signal, then it will abort; and if core dumps are enabled, then one will be produced. You may need to enable core dumps, perhaps using `ulimit -c unlimited` from the shell you use to launch the program.

If you overflow by a large amount, then you may instead overwrite some other part of the program's memory. If this happens, then all bets are off; the program could crash, or could continue in a corrupt state and cause any kind of damage at any point in the future.

That's assuming that, by "overflow" you mean using more stack memory than has been allocated by some combination of a deep call stack and large automatic objects. If you're talking about writing to the wrong part of the stack (e.g. by an out-of-bounds access to an automatic array), then you'll typically get random memory corruption rather than a segmentation fault; again, the program might shamble on in a corrupt state with unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow does not create a core dump file always. If you are lucky, it is just a simple overrun of your stack, some local variables or buffers are overwritten. It might not cause any abnormal behavior of your program, and no core dump file.

However, if the stack overflow overwrites some local variables which are pointers, or the return address, when you use the pointer, which is now invalid address and points to unmapped memory page, or the program use the pointer to write to read-only pages, it causes the segmentation fault and the core dump file is created. Or the return address is overwritten, and the CPU returns to invalid addressing space or executes invalid code, it also causes the exception and a core file is created.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't call random, undetectable memory corruption "lucky".

Comment: Yes. That's the memory corruption. The lucky I mean is the program does not crash and cause core dump if it does not affect your program functionality. For example, you have a large char array. And some bytes at the tail of the array are overwritten, but somehow your function does not use the full array size this time. So, I called it is lucky your program